# MomentJS doesn't return correct date with HandlebarsJS

Tags: jsonp, handlebars.js, momentjs

I'm pulling a JSONP date for different events and workshops from RegOnline, which gives me:

```
/DATE(1408545000000)/
```

I'm using Handlebars to list the different events, and I'm attempting to use MomentJS as a registerHelper. `objs` is the array of objects I'm pulling from RegOnline:

```
function bindEvents(objs) {

    Handlebars.registerHelper('formatDate', function(objs){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(
            moment(objs.StartDate).format("LL")
        );
    });

    var eventHost = $("#eventHost").html();
    var eventTpl = Handlebars.compile(eventHost);
    $(".event-list").append(eventTpl(objs));

}
```

Here's my template:

```
<span class="timestamp">{{City}}, {{State}} - {{formatDate StartDate}}</span>
```

This gives me the current date, instead of the date of the event. What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us how do you pass data to template?

Comment: var eventHost = $("#eventHost").html();
    var eventTpl = Handlebars.compile(eventHost);
    $(".event-list").append(eventTpl(objs));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I didn't need to define `objs.StartDate` in the Moment line. Handlebars takes care of that for me, so I just needed to use `objs`.